# jQuery validation without form tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a "form" with many inputs and at the submit button I call a javascript function that manipulate the info and send by ajax to a php file..

I can add a form tag without an action url to validate my "form" with the jquery validate? Or I have to do manually the validation?

Thanks!

Comment: I've more than fully answered your very basic question and provided working examples.  If you want specific answers about why your own code is broken, you are going to have to **show the code**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> "I have a 'form' with many inputs and at the submit button I call a
>   javascript function that manipulate the info and send by ajax to a php
>   file"

It is absolutely required that you have `<form></form>` tags for the jQuery Validate plugin to function properly, or at all.

If you use `ajax`, you must [put your `ajax` inside the `submitHandler` of the jQuery Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).  See below for my example.

> "I can add a form tag without an action url to validate my "form" with the jquery validate?"

Yes, you can remove or block the `action` and still use jQuery Validate.

See demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/NEPsc/3/

Put your `ajax` and a `return false` in the `submitHandler` and no regular submission will occur:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize plugin
        // your rules & options,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // your ajax would go here
            return false;  // blocks regular submit since you have ajax
        }
    });

});
```

---

**EDIT**:

As per OP's comments, to use a `input type="button"` instead of a `input type="submit"`, you'll need to use a `click` handler.  **There is no need to have any inline JavaScript.  Remove the `onClick` function entirely.**

**See updated demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/NEPsc/5/**

Comment: "It is absolutely required that you have <form></form> tags for the jQuery Validate plugin to function properly, or at all." 
This is a complete bugger when my HTML is served in an ASP.NET app and is all wrapped in a `<form>` tag for the codebehind stuff to work.  My embedded `<form>` gets stripped out and isn't in the DOM when jquery has a chance to look at it.