# Validating password Match in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to validate both passwords field and checking that both of them match but the form still gives an error even if both input boxes have the same password.

**JS**

```
var validator = $("#signupform").validate({
  rules: {
    password: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 6
    },

    repeatpassword: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 6,
      equalTo: "#password"
    }

  },
  messages: {
    password: {
      required: "Provide a password",
      minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
    },
    repeatpassword: {
      required: "Repeat your password",
      minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters"),
      equalTo: "Your passwords do not match"
    }
  },
});
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" tabindex="5">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" name="repeatpassword" id="repeatpassword" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password" tabindex="6">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well equalTo is in repeatpassword input box

Comment: Is your validator inside $(document).ready(function() ?

Comment: watch this video on this page: http://jqueryvalidation.org

Comment: I think your `repeatpassword` should be `confirm_password`

Comment: whats in the name it should not matter

Comment: @LeoFarmer yes it is

Comment: I don't see the library in your html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you knew this but, "It is absolutely required that you have `<form></form>` tags for the jQuery Validate plugin to function properly, or at all." [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231847/jquery-validation-without-form-tag)

So I added a form tag.

What I think the issue with the passwords was, your were doing this:

```
jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
```

There is an error in console:

> "$.format has been deprecated. Please use $.validator.format instead.";

So I changed your code to:

> jQuery.**validator**.format("Enter at least {0} characters")

```js
var validator = $("#signupform").validate({
  rules: {
    password: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 6
    },

    repeatpassword: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 6,
      equalTo: "#password"
    }

  },
  messages: {
    password: {
      required: "Provide a password",
      minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
    },
    repeatpassword: {
      required: "Repeat your password",
      minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Enter at least {0} characters"),
      equalTo: "Your passwords do not match"
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="signupform">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" tabindex="5">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" name="repeatpassword" id="repeatpassword" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password" tabindex="6">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Does not solves the problem the error gets displayed even when both the passwords are same

Comment: That is not happening in the code snippet above, but sorry it did not help you.

Comment: You are right it is working but on my website it is displaying the error. And my files get uploaded automatically when a change is made so there is not issue with the files transfer. But thanks for help

Comment: @Jonast92 you are right my sign In password field was being matched with my sign up password field sorry about that